# generic parameter 'FalseContent' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a 4x4 grid of images, and I'd like it to scale from 1 image up to 4.

This code works when the images provided come from a regular array

```
var images = ["imageOne", "imageTwo", "imageThree", "imageFour"]
```

However it does not work if the array comes from an object we are bound to:

```
@ObjectBinding var images = ImageLoader() //Where our array is in images.images
```

My initialiser looks like this:

```
init(imageUrls urls: [URL]){
    self.images = ImageLoader(urls)
}
```

And my `ImageLoader` class looks like this:

```
class ImageLoader: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<ImageLoader, Never>()

    var images = [UIImage]() {
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.didChange.send(self)
            }
        }
    }

    init(){

    }

    init(_ urls: [URL]){
        for image in urls{
            //Download image and append to images array
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises in my `View`

```
var body: some View {
    return VStack {
        if images.images.count == 1{
            Image(images.images[0])
                .resizable()
        } else {
            Text("More than one image")
        }
    }
}
```

Upon compiling, I get the error `generic parameter 'FalseContent' could not be inferred`, where `FalseContent` is part of the SwiftUI `buildEither(first:)` function.

Again, if `images`, instead of being a binding to `ImageLoader`, is a regular array of `String`s,  it works fine.

I'm not sure what is causing the issue, it seems to be caused by the binding, but I'm not sure how else to do this.

Comment: Hey Kontiki, sorry, you're right there is errors. I tried to make it more succinct, but I'll. fix it

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: I think I was able to reconstruct your code into something workable. Sorry to be a pain, but just to be sure: Is `init(imageUrls urls: [URL])` the initialiser of your view?

Comment: Yeah that's the initialiser

Comment: Got it, posted the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your Image initialiser, your passing a UIImage, so you should call it like this:

```swift
Image(uiImage: images.images[0])
```

*Note that when dealing with views, flow control is a little complicated and error messages can be misleading. By commenting the "else" part of the IF statement of your view, the compiler would have shown you the real reason why it was failing.*

Comment: Oh god your'e right. Thank you for the help! Hopefully errors improve :)

Comment: I found that the best way to debug view body errors, specially when they do not make sense, is to start commenting things out. They either go away and tell you where the problem is coming from, or they change into something that actually makes sense.

Comment: That note is the real MVP, commenting the else out lead me to find the problem. The compiler warnings are batty!